# Setting a value of class variable from another function

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm working on a simple arcade style space shooter and I'm having some problems with my `player` class.

This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

class player {
    public:
        int xPos, yPos;
        void setPlayerPos(int x, int y);
        int getX();
        int getY();
};

void player::setPlayerPos(int x, int y) {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    return;
}
int player::getX() {
    return xPos;
}
int player::getY() {
    return yPos;
}
void onGameStart() {
    player Player;
    Player.setPlayerPos(3,10);
}

void main() {
    onGameStart();
    while (gameIsRunning) {
        onGameDraw();
    }
}
```

Of course, everything starts in `main()` on the bottom of the code. It runs a simple `onGameStart()` function which is supposed to set the player's beginning coordinates.

Here is the thing. When I set the values of `xPos` and `yPos` when initializing those variables, `Player.getX()` and `Player.getY()` will always return the correct value. However, when set them using `Player.setPlayerPos(x,y)`, then `Player.getX()` and `Player.getY()` returns junk. (Or original initialized values, if set).

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and why `Player.setPlayerPos(x,y)` does not update `xPos` and `yPos`.

Comment: You only have one player, which is local to `onGameStart`. Where exactly are you observing this behaviour? (I suspect that you have another variable that's also called "Player", but things are not the same just because they share a name – ask John Smith.)

Comment: ***what I'm doing wrong and why Player.setPlayerPos(x,y) does not update xPos and yPos.*** Difficult to tell since you don't show the code that does that..

Comment: In your example, you are updating the local variable `Player` inside the function `onGameStart`, you haven't posted `onGameDraw` at all, so we can't see what that does, but if you are creating another local variable `Player` (or similar), then that would contain the unintialized `{x, y}` from an uninitialized `player` object, explaining the randomness. You probably want to either pass the `Player` from main into your different `onGameXXXX` functions, or have a `Game` object that holds one or more players.

Comment: The following object: `player Player;` is local to `void onGameStart()` function. Once that function goes out of scope it is destroyed.

Comment: Maybe you assumed that creating an additional variable named `Player` would somehow give you access to the values that you set in this local `Player`. However this is not how c++ works.

Comment: Not related to the problem:   [`void main()` is notoriously incorrect](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main). Additional advice: use lowercase for object names and [capitalize user-defined types](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rl-knr). You can do the contrary as you did for player, but this is confusing as it's contrary to common practice (e.g. Cpp Core Guidelines, [Google Style guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Type_Names),  and many more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a variable in main like this:

```
class player {
    public:
        int xPos, yPos;
        void setPlayerPos(int x, int y);
        int getX();
        int getY();
};

void player::setPlayerPos(int x, int y) {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
    return;
}
int player::getX() {
    return xPos;
}
int player::getY() {
    return yPos;
}
void onGameStart(player & Player) {
    Player.setPlayerPos(3,10);
}

int main() {
    player Player;
    onGameStart(Player);
    while (gameIsRunning) {
        onGameDraw(Player); // Need to know more about the implementation but it should be similiar to onGameStart.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to do it for me. Thank you. Thanks you for answers guys, I've read them all. So from what I understood, each time I initialize Player, I'm creating a local instance for that function only. In order to set the value for this 'instance' in other functions I need to pass it on from function to function.

Comment: @Ziphold no problem

Answer (score 1):

your code seems not to be complete ...

this code seems to be not usable:

```
void onGameStart() {
    player Player;
    Player.setPlayerPos(3,10);
}
```

because you are changing the local variable - those player is destroyed outside of function scope. The player you are using in your code is probably some other instance - so it's x and y are not those set in your function, but some junk x and y value - because you are not initializing them in the constructor.

If you declare those player Player globaly (which is not a good practice) then your code should work (but global variables are always bad idea). Maybe try passing those player via pointer or reference to the function onGameStart

Answer (score 1):

In the function `onGameStart` you are creating a local variable player and you set its position but then after the function ends you can no longer access it, so it is useless. Maybe you want to have a global variable player and set its position on game start? I suspect you are confusing the local variable and another one which you aren't modifying from this function and you aren't getting the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

The following object: `player Player;` is **local** to your freestanding `void onGameStart()` function. Once that function goes out of scope the object gets destroyed. Your other object's data members remain uninitialized hence the garbage values. Your local object has nothing to do with other (main?) objects you have in a program:

```
int main() {
    player p;
    onGameStart(); // only modifies its internal object, not the p
    std::cout << p.getX(); // prints garbage because xPos is uninitialized
    std::cout << p.getY(); // prints garbage because yPos is uninitialized
}
```

And if you want the `onGameStart()` function to be able to modify the object one way is to pass the object by reference:

```
void onGameStart(player& p) {
    p.setPlayerPos(3, 10);
}
```

Now this code prints 3 and 10:

```
int main() {
    player p;
    onGameStart(p); // now modifies the p
    std::cout << p.getX(); // prints 3
    std::cout << p.getY(); // prints 10
}
```

Maybe that's the confusion. Initialize your data members in a constructor:

```
class player {
public:
    int xPos, yPos;
    player() : xPos(0), yPos(0) {}
};
```